# text not showing within javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.test').text('Hello');
})
```

in addition my javascript function..

```
 function format ( d ) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
        return '<div class="slider">'+
            '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<td colspan="2"><div class="test"></div></td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '</table>'+
            '</div>';
    }
```

When i call test class within format function then "Hello" text not showing but i write plain text like ... Something  then showing.

Please can help me anyone....

**##Important##**
format function use another place

Comment: u need to insert that html into DOM to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change text using `$('.test').text('Hello');` this when ".test" is in function.
You can add delay in adding text like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').delay(1000).text('Hello');
})
```